# why jquery position() method does not have a setter version

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently studying jquery and have noticed most of the method in jquery have a setting and getter version. i.e. the method is used as a setter or as a getter, depending on the type/number of arguments passed to the method.

A example would be the [jquery offset() method](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

But I have also noticed that the [jquery position() method](https://api.jquery.com/position/) only have a getter version, and its setter version is missing.

Does anyone have any idea why the `position()` method does not have a setter version? I'm not exactly sure but I think a setter version would be useful in certain situations.

Comment: Probably because [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) and [`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) are read-only properties

Comment: so if we can't set `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` property, what impact would it have? As in, is there any instances where setting `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` would be potentially useful?

Comment: Because the position of an element behaves differently depending on the css position property, plus jquery has css setters for position so it would just be redundant anyway and add to the size of the library for no reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `offset()` and `position()` are quite different, both by their purpose and under the hood. Authors tried to explain it in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/position/):

> The `.position()` method allows us to retrieve the current position of
>   an element (specifically its margin box) *relative to the offset parent*
>   (**specifically its padding box, which excludes margins and borders**).
>   Contrast this with `.offset()`, which retrieves the current position
>   *relative to the document*.

But the best explanation is, as usual, in the source. [`offset()` getter](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.12.4/src/offset.js#L81) is fairly simple: after checking that element's presence in live DOM, compare its box against the document's one, adjust by scroll:

```
// If we don't have gBCR, just use 0,0 rather than error
// BlackBerry 5, iOS 3 (original iPhone)
if ( typeof elem.getBoundingClientRect !== "undefined" ) {
    box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
}
win = getWindow( doc );
return {
    top: box.top  + ( win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop )  - ( docElem.clientTop  || 0),
    left: box.left + ( win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft ) - ( docElem.clientLeft || 0 )
};
```

<sub>*(It's even more straightforward in 2.x branch, btw; no need for gBCR check)*</sub>

---

Now, [`position()` getter](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.12.4/src/offset.js#L118) is *relatively* simple only if the target element has `position: fixed` applied - just take the gBCR results for offsets.

Otherwise, things get messy. First, the algorithm should locate the 'real' offsetParent - the closest predecessor with position other than static. If none found, `documentElement` is used instead:

```
// key part of `offsetParent()` method
while ( offsetParent && ( !jQuery.nodeName( offsetParent, "html" ) &&
       jQuery.css( offsetParent, "position" ) === "static" ) ) {
    offsetParent = offsetParent.offsetParent;
}
return offsetParent || documentElement;
```

Then the code calculates the `offsetParent` offset - uses its coords if it's `documentElement`, or `top: 0, left: 0` instead. And don't forget about borders!

```
var parentOffset = { top: 0, left: 0 },
// ... later on
if ( !jQuery.nodeName( offsetParent[ 0 ], "html" ) ) {
    parentOffset = offsetParent.offset();
}
// Add offsetParent borders
parentOffset.top  += jQuery.css( offsetParent[ 0 ], "borderTopWidth", true );
parentOffset.left += jQuery.css( offsetParent[ 0 ], "borderLeftWidth", true );
```

Finally, offsets are compared - and now margins of the element are taken into account as well:

```
// Subtract parent offsets and element margins
// note: when an element has margin: auto the offsetLeft and marginLeft
// are the same in Safari causing offset.left to incorrectly be 0
return {
    top:  offset.top  - parentOffset.top - jQuery.css( elem, "marginTop", true ),
    left: offset.left - parentOffset.left - jQuery.css( elem, "marginLeft", true )
};
```

---

And the third part of the puzzle, [`offset()` setter](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.12.4/src/offset.js#L31). Here are the key parts:

```
// set position first, in-case top/left are set even on static elem
if ( position === "static" ) {
    elem.style.position = "relative";
}

curOffset = curElem.offset();
curCSSTop = jQuery.css( elem, "top" );
curCSSLeft = jQuery.css( elem, "left" );
calculatePosition = ( position === "absolute" || position === "fixed" ) &&
        jQuery.inArray( "auto", [ curCSSTop, curCSSLeft ] ) > -1;

// need to be able to calculate position if either top or left
// is auto and position is either absolute or fixed
if ( calculatePosition ) {
    curPosition = curElem.position();
    curTop = curPosition.top;
    curLeft = curPosition.left;
} else {
    curTop = parseFloat( curCSSTop ) || 0;
    curLeft = parseFloat( curCSSLeft ) || 0;
}

// ...
if ( options.top != null ) {
    props.top = ( options.top - curOffset.top ) + curTop;
}
if ( options.left != null ) {
    props.left = ( options.left - curOffset.left ) + curLeft;
}
// ...
curElem.css( props );
```

Essentially, it's - again - quite simple: calculate the element's offset, and modify its `top` and `left` by the difference. The complicated part covers the case of `position: fixed` in combination with `auto` values for either `top` or `left`.

---

When thinking of how `position` setter might look like, two questions arise. 
First and foremost, what should it do with static elements? As seen above, `offset` setter just rewrites their `position` into `relative`; should we go the same way here - and deal with `offsetParent` sudden changes?

Second, each time that setter is called, it should recalculate the padding box of `offsetParent`. Of course, it hugely depends on use-cases, but - shouldn't we do this calculation only when the element is mount, and redo on layout-changing events? And if we should, perhaps `offset()` setter alongside existing `css({top, left})` already covers all our needs?

Those concerns might explain why this option is not implemented yet in jQuery - despite the fact it's already there in [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/). That plugin doesn't have dependencies on other jQuery UI components, but [its latest version](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.12.1/ui/position.js) is ~500 lines long.

If you do think that it should be a part of jQuery too, just raise a corresponding issue on jQuery tracker; at least I didn't find [anything related](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+position) yet.